# Different y scales in one python plot

Tags: python, plot

I want to make a plot as the one attached

[image: Plot]

Where it has two y axes with different scales and all the parameters names are identified by colors in the small upper left box.

I tried the following

```
    plt.figure()
    p1, = plt.plot(s_pos, beta_x)
    p2, = plt.plot(s_pos, beta_y)
    plt.legend([p1, p2], [r'$\beta_x$', r'$\beta_y$'])
    p3, = plt.plot(s_pos, dx)
    plt.legend([p3], [r'$\eta_x$'])
```

But it showed the eta in the same scale of the plots (s_pos, betax, beta y) y axes and also it give me the eta only in the small box.

[image: plot2]

Comment: You are looking for `ax.twinx()`. [Matplotlib provides ample examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) that you can adapt.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following adapted from the examples:

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
    host = host_subplot(111)

    par = host.twinx()

    host.set_xlabel("s_pos")
    host.set_ylabel(r'$\beta_x$')
    host.set_ylabel(r'$\beta_y$')
    par.set_ylabel("dx")

    p1, = host.plot(s_pos, beta_x, label=r'$\beta_x$')
    p2, = host.plot(s_pos, beta_y, label=r'$\beta_y$')
    p3, = par.plot(s_pos, dx, label=r'$\eta_x$')

    leg = plt.legend()

    host.yaxis.get_label().set_color(p1.get_color())
    leg.texts[0].set_color(p1.get_color())

    host.yaxis.get_label().set_color(p2.get_color())
    leg.texts[1].set_color(p2.get_color())

    par.yaxis.get_label().set_color(p3.get_color())
    leg.texts[2].set_color(p3.get_color())

    plt.show()
```

[image: plot4]